# Why does the function Integrate give a different result?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

It seems that `Integrate` gives a different result when a integrand is in an different form.

```
eps*Derivative[1, 0][p][s, x] == Derivative[2, 0, 0][v][r, s, x] + eps*Derivative[1, 0, 0][v][r, s, x] - eps^2*v[r, s, x]; 
dsol = Flatten[DSolve[{%, v[0, s, x] == 0, v[1, s, x] == 0}, v, {r, s, x}]]; 
vel = Simplify[ExpToTrig[v[r, s, x] /. dsol]]; 
velAvg = Simplify[ExpToTrig[Integrate[vel, {r, 0, 1}]]]; 
vp[r_] = vel/velAvg; 
ruleV = v -> (vp[#1]*v[#2, #3] & );
```

`vp` is expressed using trigonometric functions.

```
Integrate[(-eps^2)*v[r, s, x] + 
    eps^2*Derivative[0, 0, 2][v][r, s, x] + 
    eps^2*Derivative[0, 2, 0][v][r, s, x] + 
    eps*Derivative[1, 0, 0][v][r, s, x] + 
         Derivative[2, 0, 0][v][r, s, x] /. ruleV, {r, 0, 1}]; 
Collect[%, v[__], Simplify]
```

gives
[image]
, but

```
Integrate[
  TrigToExp[(-eps^2)*v[r, s, x] + 
     eps^2*Derivative[0, 0, 2][v][r, s, x] + 
     eps^2*Derivative[0, 2, 0][v][r, s, x] + 
     eps*Derivative[1, 0, 0][v][r, s, x] + 
           Derivative[2, 0, 0][v][r, s, x] /. ruleV], {r, 0, 1}]; 
Collect[%, v[__], Simplify]
```

gives
[image]
These are not equivalent.
Why does this happen?

Comment: What do you get when you equate the two integrals? `int1 == int2 // Simplify` or `int1 == int2 // FullSimplify`

Comment: @BobHanlon It returns `((-1 + E^(Sqrt[5]*eps))*eps*(Derivative[0, 2][v][s, x] +Derivative[2, 0][v][s, x]))/(Sqrt[5]*Cosh[eps/2] - Sqrt[5]*Cosh[(Sqrt[5]*eps)/2] +eps*Sinh[(Sqrt[5]*eps)/2]) == 0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get different results which are consistent (equal).

```
$Version

(* "12.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

eps*Derivative[1, 0][p][s, x] == 
  Derivative[2, 0, 0][v][r, s, x] + 
   eps*Derivative[1, 0, 0][v][r, s, x] - eps^2*v[r, s, x];
dsol = Flatten[
   DSolve[{%, v[0, s, x] == 0, v[1, s, x] == 0}, v, {r, s, x}]];
vel = Simplify[ExpToTrig[v[r, s, x] /. dsol]];
velAvg = Simplify[ExpToTrig[Integrate[vel, {r, 0, 1}]]];
vp[r_] = vel/velAvg;
ruleV = v -> (vp[#1]*v[#2, #3] &);

Integrate[(-eps^2)*v[r, s, x] + 
    eps^2*Derivative[0, 0, 2][v][r, s, x] + 
    eps^2*Derivative[0, 2, 0][v][r, s, x] + 
    eps*Derivative[1, 0, 0][v][r, s, x] + 
    Derivative[2, 0, 0][v][r, s, x] /. ruleV, {r, 0, 1}];
int1 = Collect[%, v[__], Simplify]
```

[image]

```
Integrate[
  TrigToExp[(-eps^2)*v[r, s, x] + 
     eps^2*Derivative[0, 0, 2][v][r, s, x] + 
     eps^2*Derivative[0, 2, 0][v][r, s, x] + 
     eps*Derivative[1, 0, 0][v][r, s, x] + 
     Derivative[2, 0, 0][v][r, s, x] /. ruleV], {r, 0, 1}];
int2 = Collect[%, v[__], Simplify]
```

[image]

```
int1 == int2 // Simplify

(* True *)
```

Comment: Thank you for the test. I have used `"12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)"`. I will try that in the new version of Mathematica.

Comment: With v12.0.0 on my Mac I get the same results as those from v12.2.0